# Not able to install Symfony 4.2.10 version

Tags: symfony-4.2

What I've tried:

I tried with:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "4.2.*"
```

But get:

> "  Could not find package symfony/framework-standard-edition with version 4.2.10."

And I need the exact one. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The package `symfony/framework-standard-edition` is for 3.4.* version. For 4.2.* you should use `symfony/website-skeleton`.

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name "4.2.*"
```

More details in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications).